# Is there similar result between simulation and reality?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aircraft-performance

While designing an aircraft and analyzing it using simulation software, one result comes out. Is what occurs on the aircraft in reality similar to the result as given in a simulation?

Comment: It would not a "simulator" if the results were ***not*** similar.

Comment: See an example comparing simulation of flight dynamics and wind tunnel for the conversion of an Avro RJ85 aircraft into a fire fighting aircraft: [Efficient high fidelity simulation of a special role aircraft in 
transonic and high lift flight regimes using ANSYS Fluent and 
ICEM Block Structured Meshing](http://www.ansys.com/staticassets/ANSYS%20UK/staticassets/Presentations/2013%20User%20Conference%20Presentations/Track%202%201555%20BAE.pdf).

Comment: Theory behind CFD software: [Computational fluid dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_fluid_dynamics).

Comment: In short: The result depends on the input. Garbage in - garbage out is very valid in simulations.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, usually

Simulators are pretty accurate, at least for the specific things they're programmed to measure and account for.

For example we have a pretty good idea how airflow works, so airfoil/wind tunnel simulation is very accurate. We also have quite good ideas of how materials react, flex, break etc, and can model them pretty accurately.

### However

No simulation is 100% accurate: there is always potential for things in the "real world" to happen in a way we either didn't account for, or weren't expecting.

For example sometimes manufacturing flaws mean a material breaks in a way we weren't expecting, or an external influence changes the way something happens. We also don't have a 100% understanding of aerodynamics under all conditions.  This is why we still need real-world testing. There are also circumstances we've never encountered and therefore can't be certain of: eg aircraft are designed to handle around 150% of the force of the strongest known/experienced turbulence, but we can't be truly sure that this hypothetical 150% turbulence would act as "regular" turbulence, merely 50% stronger

In short: yes, the results will be **similar**, but they will not *necessarily* be **identical**, depending on exactly what you are testing.